# Keyboard layout map generation

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I want to generate exactly the same than that :

[image: custom layout]

but in an **HTML** document (*whatever the locale is*)!

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You want to create an on-screen keyboard in HTML? What was your question?

Comment: I want to show up a web page with a keyboard-like table. In full HTML = no picture.

Comment: So yes, you want to create an on-screen keyboard in HTML. I suggest looking for a tutorial or some code that you can download to start with. This question is too broad as it's currently written, and doesn't appear to have anything to do with UNIX or Linux.

Comment: It's an utility for Linux, under Linux, that generates this picture, so I think maybe someone already knows how to do that under Linux, that's why I posted it under unix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution coming from a mate who is good when it comes to this kind of problems.

Using shell command `ps -Hef`, I could see `gkbd-keyboard-display -g 1` running.

There's no `man` page.

```
$ man gkbd-keyboard-display
No manual entry for gkbd-keyboard-display
See 'man 7 undocumented' for help when manual pages are not available.
```

Looking for this program:

```
$ type gkbd-keyboard-display
gkbd-keyboard-display is hashed (/usr/bin/gkbd-keyboard-display)
$ file /usr/bin/gkbd-keyboard-display
/usr/bin/gkbd-keyboard-display: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV),
    ...dynamically linked (uses shared libs),
    ...for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, BuildID[sha1]=0xc4e, [...]
```

So looking for the packet:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/gkbd-keyboard-display
gkbd-capplet: /usr/bin/gkbd-keyboard-display
$
```

Looking in the Web, found https://packages.debian.org/gkbd-capplet
Add `sid` because it's the most up-to-date version: https://packages.debian.org/sid/gkbd-capplet

From there, I clicked on the right option (`Developer's information (PTS)`) to see the source packet: it's this link: http://packages.qa.debian.org/libgnomekbd

In the right column, "`Links`" I clicked on the link "`Browse source code`" https://sources.debian.net/src/libgnomekbd/unstable/

I went into the `debian` folder then in the file `watch`, and from there I get the URL of the source code:

https://sources.debian.net/src/libgnomekbd/3.6.0-1/debian/watch/

From now on I'll have to understand how it works, and how to output all configurations in a way that I can read it in `JSON` format. Lots of work to do, but very interesting!